# How do I populate a new data frame with the information/values of another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I populate a new data frame with the information/values of another data frame?

If the original dataframe is exp.kirp.log2, the metadata column value will be kirp. If its exp.kich.log2, then metadata will be kich etc.

`exp2.log2` is a combination of 3 data frames.

```
exp.log2 <- cbind(exp.kirp.log2, exp.kirc.log2, exp.kich.log2)
```

I now want to create a new dataframe `metadata` with its rownames equal to the colnames of `exp.log2`. I then want to assign `metadata` a column with the subtype information (i.e., kirp, kirc, and kich).

```
exp.kirp.log2$subtype <- "KIRP"
exp.kirc.log2$subtype <- "KIRC"
exp.kich.log2$subtype <- "KICH"
metadata <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 0, nrow = ncol(exp.log2)))
rownames(metadata) <- colnames(exp.log2)
metadata$subtype <- exp.kirp.log2[match(rownames(metadata), colnames(exp.kirp.log2)),exp.kirp.log2$subtype]
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(exp.kirp.log2, match(rownames(metadata2), colnames(exp.kirp.log2)),  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

`exp.kirp.log2`

```
> dput(exp.kirp.log2[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(7.65342121905285, 2.03892776611756, 
-0.96100202120249, 6.35598354101006, -Inf), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(5.09389393824392, 
5.2160706644244, -Inf, 6.93597002271109, -Inf), TCGA.2Z.A9J2.01A = c(5.51854458067276, 
4.11644793551166, -Inf, 7.5307754013178, -Inf), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(4.70168212029528, 
3.34111759260469, 3.57815377007565, 7.54694769203808, -Inf), 
    TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(7.99645936536463, 5.20408983959317, 
    1.64952349150802, 6.89258167250936, -Inf)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2ML1"), class = "data.frame")
```

`exp.kirc.log2`

```
> dput(exp.kirc.log2[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.3Z.A93Z.01A = c(7.60710168395891, 6.59399907429693, 
0.912189968482442, 5.86606228532002, -0.672772532238714), TCGA.6D.AA2E.01A = c(5.29679509798346, 
5.33895561100057, -Inf, 8.5246110567563, 2.81058705767919), TCGA.A3.3306.01A = c(3.63487202316421, 
6.98654291078066, -Inf, 7.56954121842147, -Inf), TCGA.A3.3307.01A = c(4.30394874845039, 
7.75218860897157, -Inf, 6.94927811978134, -Inf), TCGA.A3.3308.01A = c(4.52027137056763, 
6.81247512149133, -0.124219936931512, 6.41770908193329, -Inf)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2ML1"), class = "data.frame")
```

`exp.kich.log2`

```
> dput(exp.kich.log2[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.KL.8323.01A = c(3.20011195634, -Inf, -Inf, 
5.86938532751066, -Inf), TCGA.KL.8324.01A = c(2.71784638377681, 
-1.08957432714833, -1.08957432714833, 6.40571672415247, -Inf), 
    TCGA.KL.8325.01A = c(3.00203636889806, 0.417055859813149, 
    2.32397526869577, 4.95203530400747, -Inf), TCGA.KL.8326.01A = c(7.05192236143441, 
    -Inf, 0.568615876713783, 5.98514745510282, -1.01624935164507
    ), TCGA.KL.8327.01A = c(5.50089763480962, -0.0840584940198524, 
    -0.0840584940198524, 4.49185309632967, -Inf)), row.names = c("A1BG", 
"A1CF", "A2BP1", "A2LD1", "A2ML1"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, you metadata dataframe will contain as many **rows** as columns contains your exp.log2 dataframe. And the subtype column will repeat for every group of rows with that corresponds to the dataframes you cbind before.It's ok?

Comment: If so, you can do `metadata <- data.frame(subtype = rep(c("KIRP", "KIRC","KICH"), c(ncol(exp.kirp.log2),ncol(exp.kirc.log2),ncol(exp.kich.log2))` and then `rownames(metadata) <- colnames(exp2.log2)`

Comment: (1) Yes, the metadata will contain as many rows as columns of exp.log2.
(2) If the original dataframe is `exp.kirp.log2`, the metadata column value will be `kirp`. If its  `exp.kich.log2`, then metadata will be `kich` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you:
I don' know wether each exp.ki?? data frame has the same number of columns, then i use `rep` in each one `ncol`.

```
metadata <- data.frame(subtype = rep(
  c("KIRP", "KIRC","KICH"), 
  c(ncol(exp.kirp.log2),ncol(exp.kirc.log2),ncol(exp.kich.log2))
rownames(metadata) <- colnames(exp2.log2)
```

Comment: each of them have different number of columns

Comment: `Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length`

Comment: It is because you append the column "subtype" at each dataframe AFTER you used cbind to create exp2.log2. Try `c(ncol(exp.kirp.log2)-1,ncol(exp.kirc.log2)-1,ncol(exp.kich.log2)-1)` instead.

Comment: Take in account also that rownames must be **unique**. Thus, if you want colnames be used as rownames, they must be all distinct.

Comment: Still the same error.